Why is new(nothrow) not working on VS Code?
I have written the following code in VScode c++
When I input a really large integer number for n (for example 1000000000000000) I want this output:
"Dynamic memory allocation failed.\nProgram will terminate."
If I run the code in VScode with g++ compiler that output is never shown.
However, when I run it in an online compiler like Programiz, the output I want is shown.
The program is as follows:
#include <iostream>
#include <new> 

int main(){
  long int n;
  std::cout << "give n : ";
  std::cin >> n;     
  
  int* a= new (std::nothrow) int[n]; // I expect new to return nullptr
                                     // if the allocation fails          
  
  if (!a) {
    std::cout << "Dynamic memory allocation failed.\nProgram will terminate.";
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

So what is the problem?
As I said, in an online compiler when I input for example 1000000000000000 as the value for the integer n the output is the desired:
give n : 1000000000000000
Dynamic memory allocation failed.
Program will terminate.

=== Code Exited With Errors ===

but in VScode the output is :
if ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
give n : 1000000000000000
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
  what():  std::bad_array_new_length

What can I do to fix this?
the problem is that I want the program to cout that the dynamic memory allocation failed if the user gives such a huge number for the integer n
I use the GCC C++ compiler (g++) and GDB debugger from mingw-w64.
I downloaded VScode version 1.92 and followed the instructions from their site https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You cannot rely on new returning nullptr if the allocation goes wrong, at least not on recent standard compliant C++ implementations (not sure which standard actually), and (std::nothrow) apparently has no effect non your implementation.
Instead you should catch and handle exceptions like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <new> 

int main() {
  long int n = 1000000000000000;
  int* a;

  try
  {
    a = new int[n];
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    // if the allocation fails
    std::cout << "Dynamic memory allocation failed.\nProgram will terminate.\n";
    return -1;
  }

  // do something with a

  delete [] a;
  return 0;
}

Another possibility, maybe more convenient for your use case, is using std::set_new_handler:
#include <iostream>
#include <new> 
#include <cstdlib>

void newhandler()
{
  std::cout << "Dynamic memory allocation failed.\nProgram will terminate.\n";
  exit(-1);
  return;
}

int main() {
  std::set_new_handler(newhandler);

  long int n = 1000000000000000;

  int *a = new int[n]; // I expect new to return nullptr

  // do something with a;

  delete [] a;
  return 0;
}

As soon as new goes wrong, newhandler() will be called, which takes care of displaying your error message and then quits using the exit function.

The new_handler won't help if the exception is thrown before operator new[] is even called.

@MarcGlisse in which case could that happen?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Dynamic_arrays if the number of elements is negative, for instance.

If you are on Windows, then long int n is a 32-bit integral value, or you build a 32-bit application on other platforms. When you enter 1000000000000000 you get the integer overflow and the negative value -1530494976 in n. new int[n] with a negative value throws std::bad_array_new_length. Note, this exception is not what is disabled by std::nothrow operator new overload.
https://godbolt.org/z/sf4GKszKd
Update the declaration long long n or uint64_t n after #include <cstdint>.

Compiler has limitation for allocation Demo for gcc: "size '2147483648' of array exceeds maximum object size '2147483647'" (2147483647 is 0x7FFF'FFFF).

Before C++11 it was Undefined Behaviour to pass a negative array size. With C++11 and later it must throw or return nullptr in the case of nothrow new. Maybe OP is compiling for C++98.

Tactical note: Even after this mistake is corrected you may still find no error is reported as 1000000000000000 ints is likely within the bounds of what the OS will virtually allocate. This will be seen as acceptable until at some point in the future the program actually makes use of the allocation and pages of real memory are assigned. Then the program will either crash because the OS can't make good on the promised memory or run very slowly as pages are swapped in and out of RAM and to a much larger, slower medium like the swap file on a disk drive.

As previously noticed in new(std::nothrow) int[n] throws an exception, this is a GCC bug.
(these links were already posted as comments, but they were deleted / moved to chat)

From as-if rule

New-expression has another exception from the as-if rule: the compiler may remove calls to the replaceable allocation functions even if a user-defined replacement is provided and has observable side-effects.

so, we might consider that int* a = new (std::nothrow) int[n]; always succeed.
resulting in program
int main(){
  long int n;
  std::cout << "give n : ";
  std::cin >> n;
}

You might see here that clang optimize out the allocation (and didn't output message) whereas gcc doesn't optimize and do the call, and so, print the message.

The question asks why they get bad_array_new_length in some cases, and this answer explains why they may get no output in other cases, that doesn't seem to match...
